# How to hide vertical stripe during scrolling in listview/gridview?

Tags: java, android

Android. How to hide vertical stripe during scrolling in listview/gridview? 
And how to locate these views in ALL screen, i have small gorizontal lines in top and bottom of screen while I am scrolling it?

Comment: set scrollbar none in xml

Comment: @VivekMishra set scrollbars="none" not false

Answer (score 0):

Just Use like this in xml layout

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below line in xml of Listview

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

And if you want to do it from within your class

```
View.setVericalScrollbarEnabled(false) //for vertical scrollbar
View.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false) //for horizontal scrollbar
```